# Multiple Cascading Dropdowns - Infopath Form from SharePoint List

Tags: infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have what is probably a simple issue.  I have a SharePoint list with an text column (address)  and two lookup columns for classification (Customer & Warehouse).

Address ---- Customer ---- Warehouse

Customer (XYZ) has three locations A, B or C - Locations A and B are near each other and are serviced from the same warehouse - Location C is serviced from another warehouse.

I am creating an infopath form where the user selects the customer.  The address dropdown then only shows the related addresses (Locations A, B and C). I have that working.

Next, I trying to populate a read only text box with the warehouse code that is related to that address.  That is where I am having a real problem.  I have a feeling it is a simple solution, but I either get no data or I get the complete list of warehouses.

Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I followed this blog and it was a cake walk..
http://basquang.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010/

please try this....

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.